# NEST: How can I do different operations and mapping types in one bulk request?

Tags: elasticsearch, bulkinsert, nest, elasticsearch-net, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I have a list of "event" objects. Each event has its operation (delete, update, index, etc), its mapping type (document, folder, etc.), and the actual content to be indexed into Elasticsearch, if any. I don't know what any of these operations will be in advance. How can I use NEST to dynamically choose the bulk operation and mapping type for each of these events?

Answer (score 0):

`Bulk` method on `ElasticClient` should fit your requirements.

You can pass various bulk operations into the`BulkRequest`, this is a simple usage:

```
var bulkRequest = new BulkRequest();
bulkRequest.Operations = new List<IBulkOperation>
{
    new BulkCreateDescriptor<Document>().Id(1).Document(new Document{}),
    new BulkDeleteDescriptor<Document>().Id(2)
};

var bulkResponse = client.Bulk(bulkRequest);
```

Hope it helps.